# Update value in a column based on another column in the same table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is having 3 columns

1. vid - auto increment column
2. video_id - containing numbers
3. a_id -  containing junk numbers

The table looks like below.

```
Vid    Video_id    a_id
101     1            3
102     1            3
103     5            3
104     5            3
105     5            3
106     11           3
107     11           3
108     11           3
109     11           3
110     11           3
```

I want to update a_id column values based on video_id values. Values in a_id should be updated as below.ex: If there are five 11 digit in video_id then the value in a_id should be updated 1 through 5.

```
Vid    Video_id    a_id
101     1            1
102     1            2
103     5            1
104     5            2
105     5            3
106     11           1
107     11           2
108     11           3
109     11           4
110     11           5
```

Comment: Is Video_id an updatable field? If not, then you could add a after insert trigger which gets the COUNT value of video_id's rows and then update the inserted row with the correct value. Otherwise you need to launch an after update trigger too, which change all the video_id's rows (like in the @m-khalid-junaid answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use user defined variables to give rank for each video group and then join with your real table by your auto increment column and update a_id accordingly

```
update t
join (
    SELECT 
    Vid,
    @r:= CASE WHEN Video_id = @g THEN @r+1  ELSE @r:=1 END a_id 
    ,@g:=Video_id
    FROM t,(SELECT @r:=0,@g:=0) t1
    ORDER BY Video_id
) t1
on(t.Vid =t1.Vid)
set t.a_id = t1.a_id
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb747/2)